# How to combine ALT shortcuts and pinned app tabs in Firefox 4?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, browser-tabs

I usually switch between tabs using the <kbd>Alt</kbd> shortcuts; for example, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> switches to the second tab. With Firefox 4 this has become problematic as soon as tabs are pinned as application tabs. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> will now switch to the first pinned application tab, where I would prefer it to switch to the first regular tab. Is it possible to modify Firefox in such a way that we get the old behavior?

I know of the Better App Tab Shortcuts add-on, unfortunately it does not seem to work under Ubuntu.

Comment: Better App Tab Shortcuts is my extension. The problem with the current version is that it overwrites the `alt` shortcuts with Windows style `ctrl` ones. I have new version which should fix this. Let me know if you want to help by testing it.